# i am not able to validate the captcha whether it is wrong or right using Javascript

Tags: javascript, captcha

This is Javascript

```
<script>
    function q_form_val() {
        var patt = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
        var captcha_entered = document.getElementById("captcha_entered").value;
        if (captcha_entered == "") {
            alert("Please enter the Captcha");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

This is HTML code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3"><font color="#FF0000">*</font><strong>Captcha</strong>
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <?php echo '<img src="captcha.php" alt="captcha">'; ?>
            <br/>
            <span><input name="captcha_entered" type="text"  class="form-control" id="captcha_entered" size="27" maxlength="4"/></br></span>
            <input type="hidden" name="captcha_total" id="captcha_total" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['rand_code']; ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <center>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                document.write("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" class=\"btn1\"/>");
            </script>
            <noscript>
                <p style="color: red;"><b><i>Please enable JavaScript to continue</i></b>
                    <p>
            </noscript>
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

i am able to check the captcha whether it is empty or not
but i am not able to check whether it is wrong or right captcha 
i think i should add more code in javascript for verfiying whether it is              wrong or right?

Comment: Please format your code. `<>` icon in editor represents code section. Paste your code in necessary window and use `Tidy` button to indent.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`RegExp.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test). It will return true/false if the passed in string passes a test of the pattern

```
function q_form_val() {
    var patt = new RegExp(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/);
    var captcha_entered = document.getElementById("captcha_entered").value;
    if (captcha_entered == "") {
        alert("Please enter the Captcha");
        return false;
    }else if(!patt.test(captcha_entered)){
        alert("Bad Captcha Match");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

## EDIT

If you're actually trying to compare to the value of your hidden field to what was entered (the code about regex is not useful), and you would use the following code:

```
function q_form_val() {
    var captcha_entered = document.getElementById("captcha_entered").value;
    var captcha_total = document.getElementById("captcha_total").value;
    if (captcha_entered == "") {
        alert("Please enter the Captcha");
        return false;
    }else if(captcha_total !== captcha_entered)){
        alert("Bad Captcha code");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: dude ....now with your code it working for wrong captcha .......but it is not working with right captcha......if right captcha is given then it should submit the form

Comment: Can you supply an example of a "correct" captcha please.. is it an email address?

Comment: if i put a wrong capctha it is  showing me Bad captcha......but if i put right captcha then also it is showing me Bad captcha ......?

Comment: > _Can you supply an example of a "correct" captcha please_

Comment: for eg if there is captcha   4415  and i am putting 5642 then it is showing me pop up as  "Bad captcha" and if i put 4415 which is valid captcha still i m getting the same pop up as "Bad captcha".......can u please help me with this ......

Comment: @Diwakaryadav, your regex `patt` that is being used to "test" the string.. is a "famous" regex for testing valid _email_ addresses. It should *NOT* be used to test if the text in an image matches what is entered.. Im guessing you're _actually_ trying to compare it to the value that you've inserted into your hidden field?

Comment: I have updated my code to answer how you want to do it.. but as @Gwellin stated, purely client side verification of a captcha is practically useless for any kind of "human" detecting

Comment: yeaaah i know client side verification of a captcha is practically useless for any kind of "human" detecting ......but editted code totally not working at all for empty ,wrong and right.....why don't you edit in the first solution you provided to me

Comment: Because it depends what you are considering "wrong" and "right".. if the idea is that you will be verifying the captcha result on the server, but the user must enter an email address in order to proceed, then the code may work.. your original question does not explain what you're trying to do other than "verify" an input field.. and your supplied code includes a completely superfluous yet recognisable RegExp? Can you not read from the "Edit" section of my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The question is whether you *should* verify a captcha using Javascript. The whole purpose of a captcha is to circumvent automated scripts, but including the answer in the HTML makes it incredibly easy to bypass.

You should verify the captcha on the server, either through a form submit or AJAX request.